# custom selectbox bug with bootstrap modal box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to use a custom select box with some different css and search feature in a bootstrap modal box. This is simply the code for select:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen.css">
  <select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="2">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="United States">United States</option>
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
   </select>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
var config = {
  '.chosen-select'           : {},
  '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
  '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
  '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
  '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
}
for (var selector in config) {
  $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
}
  </script>
```

The question is, the select looks just fine when used outside of the modal box. However, when used in a modal box, everything's width for select is like 10px. What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.
Edit: I just tried setting it's width by jquery, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in how you setup the chosen plugin. Using the bare minimum setup with a custom width works fine:

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({width: "95%"});
```

and:

http://jsfiddle.net/0h4fowp5/1/